# Excel 2007 Macro to count and sum undefined number of rows and colums

Tags: excel, vba

I have this statement that is generated to an excel sheet from our core system as raw data (unformated). Unfortunatly it is almost impossible to format it during the generation process. Therefore I am trying to format it using a recorded macro sheet to count the rows and sum the values in the columns. Please keep in mind that the number of rows are undefined, meaning that the macro should work on any given number of rows. In other words, I'm trying to create a macro sheet to format sheet (1)into sheet (2)
Please check the images and the excel sheets.

**Note:** Visa card numbers start with the number (4) Mastercard start with (5).

**UnFormatted Sheet(1) + Sheet (2)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get things started, you will have to edit the code to add formats and additional text, but you should be able to do it.

I assume the numbers that start with 4 are Visa, and 5's are MC

```
Sub Do_ItDo_It_Good()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim Vrw As Long, MCrw As Long
    Dim vsum1 As Range, vsum2 As Range, vsum3 As Range
    Dim Mcsum1 As Range, Mcsum2 As Range, MCsum3 As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")
    sh.Cells.Delete
    With ws
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(Rws, "D"))
    End With

    With sh
        .Range("A1") = "Something 1"
        .Range("A2") = "Something 2"
        .Range("A3") = "Something 3"
        .Range("A4") = "Something 4"
        .Range("A5") = "Something 5"
        .Range("A6") = "Something 6"
        .Range("A9") = "Visa"

        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            If c Like "4*" Then c.Offset(0, -3).Range("A1:I1").Copy .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Next c
        Vrw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set vsum1 = .Cells(Vrw + 3, "E")
        Set vsum2 = .Cells(Vrw + 3, "G")
        Set vsum3 = .Cells(Vrw + 3, "H")
        vsum1 = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(11, "E"), .Cells(Vrw, "E")))
        vsum2 = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(11, "G"), .Cells(Vrw, "G")))
        vsum3 = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(11, "H"), .Cells(Vrw, "H")))
        .Cells(Vrw + 7, 1) = "Master Card"

        For Each c In Rng.Cells
            If c Like "5*" Then c.Offset(0, -3).Range("A1:I1").Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Next c
        MCrw = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Mcsum1 = .Cells(MCrw + 3, "E")
        Set Mcsum2 = .Cells(MCrw + 3, "G")
        Set MCsum3 = .Cells(MCrw + 3, "H")
        Mcsum1 = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(Vrw + 8, "E"), .Cells(MCrw, "E")))
        Mcsum2 = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(Vrw + 8, "G"), .Cells(MCrw, "G")))
        MCsum3 = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(Vrw + 8, "H"), .Cells(MCrw, "H")))



    End With

End Sub
```